# ReactJS dynamic templates (e.g. for A/B testing a web app)

Tags: reactjs

What would be the best way to have dynamic templates in ReactJS so that the same layout component can load a different template depending on some JSON response (can be mocked for this example)?

Comment: are you using react-router?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple approaches for handling this :

Since you are using react-router, your routes can contain information containing the a/b testing parameters and accordingly the different templates will be rendered for different A/B tests.

```
render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="/pricing-strategy-optimistic/products" component={OptimisticPricingPage}/>
      <Route path="/pricing-strategy-normative/products" component={NormativePricingPage}/>
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

Your `App` component will be responsible for identifying which route to redirect to depending on A/B test and accordingly redirect to the relevant nested route.

However this gets a little tricky to handle if users share urls of pages on social sites. It may be undesirable to leave indications in URL that different users are being presented to different content in a variety of contexts.

I typically prefer not to rely on URLs for A/B tests for this reason, and because it breaks bookmarking if tests change often. Query parameters alleviates this but the issue above still remains. I prefer the url to be a definitive identifier identifying the page - irrespective of variations of specifics of embedded entities.

Another disadvantage is that the component you are not displaying to the users is also loaded in the page. This is usually not a problem if the app is small, but for larger sites we this can be a potential scope for optimization.

An arguably better strategy would be to use [webpack definePlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin) to pass A/B test specific variables which will replaced in code at build time, to create multiple builds that render different components for the same set of routes.

For example if your code contains:

```
if(PRICING_STRATEGY == 'optimistic')
    console.log('optimistic')
if(PRICING_STRATEGY == 'normative')
    console.log('normative')
```

Webpack build with PRICING_STRATEGY defined as 'optimistic' will compile the above to:

```
if('optimistic' == 'optimistic')
    console.log('optimistic')
if('optimistic' == 'normative') 
  console.log('normative')
```

A minifier like uglifyjs can detect the dead code and reduce the above to:

```
console.log('optimistic')
```

This approach will of course have to be augmented with some additional server side logic to determine which asset is to be delivered to the user.